# Virtual Sitecore Usergroup - UK June 10

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

When (UTC): Thursday, June 10, 2021 16:00

RSVP: https://scug.co.uk/events/2021/06/london-sagittarius-sitecore-usergroup/

UK Sitecore User Group

We'll have speakers talking about using GraphQL with Sitecore to create experiences that convert, how to get lightning performance from the system and last but by no means least we'll listen to what backend developers need to learn to use and maximise Sitecore's headless technologies. If that wasn't enough, join us for a quiz where you can win a £50 Amazon gift voucher (courtesy of Sagittarius)!

Agenda (UTC): 
16:00 – 16:05 Arrival and Opening
16:05 – 17:20 Sessions
17:20 – 17:20 Quiz
17:20 - Closing

Presentations:

Natalie Waite & Peter Clisby: Graph QL for Sitecore
Nikolay Mitikov: Makin' it faster
Peter Prochazka: From Hero to Zero and back to Hero

Comment: "Community Bulletin promotion began 20 hours ago"